# How to flatten a tree-like structure in Rust to a Vec<&mut ...>?

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

I have a Tree-like structure in Rust:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Dir {
    name: String,
    children: Vec<Node>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum Node {
    File(File),
    Dir(Dir),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct FileSystem {
    root: Dir,
}
```

I wanted to flatten this structure into a `Vec<&mut Node>` (the order is not relevant).

My idea was to recursively traverse the tree and add every nodes to a vec:

```rust
impl Node {
    fn flatten(&mut self, nodes: &mut Vec<&mut Node>) {
        nodes.push(self);

        if let Node::Dir(dir) = self {
            for node in dir.children.iter_mut() {
                node.flatten(nodes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm getting an error because `self` was already moved into `nodes`, but I have no idea how to solve this problem. I've tried using `Rc` and `RefCell` but I have little knowledge about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, if it was you could get 2 mutable references to the children at the same time, one through the `self` reference and the other through the direct mutable references to the children all within the same `Vec`.

so suppose you had a tree like this:

```rust
let mut root = Dir {
    name: "root".into(),
    children: vec![],
};
let child = Dir {
    name: "child".into(),
    children: vec![],
};
root.children.push(child);
// assume this produces [&mut root, &mut root.children[0]]
let refs = root.flatten();
let child1 = &mut refs[0].children[0];
let child2 = refs[1];
```

`child1` and `child2` would both be a mutable reference to the same memory location and that's considered [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) in Rust.

You can flatten a nested structure if you put your children behind shared references and use interior mutability to get mutability back, one way to do this would be this:

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Dir {
    name: String,
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Dir>>>,
}

trait Flatten {
    fn flatten(self, flat: &mut Vec<Self>) where Self: Sized;
}
impl Flatten for Rc<RefCell<Dir>> {
    fn flatten(self, flat: &mut Vec<Self>) {
        flat.push(Rc::clone(&self));
        for child in &self.borrow().children {
            Rc::clone(child).flatten(flat);
        }
    }
}

impl Dir {
    fn new(name: impl Into<String>) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Dir {
            name: name.into(),
            children: Vec::new(),
        }))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let root = Dir::new("root");
    let child = Dir::new("child");
    let sibling = Dir::new("sibling");
    let grandchild = Dir::new("grandchild");
    child.borrow_mut().children.push(grandchild);
    root.borrow_mut().children.extend([child, sibling]);
    let mut refs = Vec::with_capacity(4);
    root.flatten(&mut refs);
    dbg!(refs);
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible if you changed `children` declaration to `Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>` to return a flattened vec?

Comment: Not a `Vec<&mut ...>` but some sort of flattened vector, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand on @cafce25's answer: You can't flatten to a `Vec<&mut Dir>` because that'd give you two ways to get a mutable reference to the same thing. One of those ways goes through `children`. Hence: you can still get a `Vec<&mut …>`, it just can't include access to `children`.

So if you for example had

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct NodeCommon {
    name: String,
    …
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Dir {
    common: NodeCommon,
    children: Vec<Node>,
}
```

you can get a `Vec<&mut NodeCommon>` with your code above. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=df6ea5797e2b56604b510267e83887fd)

Though I'd like to ask: what will you do with that `Vec`? If you're only going to iterate over it to change some things, it'd be somewhat wasteful to construct a `Vec` for that. A nicer solution to the "abstract walking over the tree" problem might be to call an `FnMut` on every `Dir`:

```rust
impl Node {
    fn for_each_dir_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, f: &mut impl FnMut(&mut Dir)) {
        if let Node::Dir(dir) = self {
            f(dir);
            for node in dir.children.iter_mut() {
                node.for_each_dir_mut(f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1115eac2c53c5d72e57de3d3514b6fb0)

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid right now. How do you pass that in the recursive call? ([Edit:] Deleted question was why it's a `&mut FnMut`, not just a `FnMut`.)

Comment: You're right that's why.

Comment: You have a point though. If this is an outside-facing API, one should probably provide a wrapper function.